# How to find Day name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to find the Name of a particular DATE (like Sunday, Monday etc.) in past. 
Suppose I have to find Day Name on

 `2000-1-1`
How can I find that ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `DATENAME` function of SQL Server, like this

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2000-1-1')
```